# Why is shell interpreting characters within single quotes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am using bash shell

```
$cat test
a --b

$grep '--b' test
grep: option `--b' is ambiguous
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.

$grep "--b" test
grep: option `--b' is ambiguous
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.

$grep '\-\-b' test
a --b
```

The classic shell scripting book in chapter 7 "Input and Output,Files, and Command Evaluation" in section 7.7 Quoting says that

> "Single quotes force the shell to treat everything between the pair of quotes literally".

Then why is single quotes not working above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shell *is* treating them literally. But the shell is not responsible for how the *application* treats them. It is up to the application to decide how it wants to handle the `--b` passed as an argument.

Comment: Exactly. For `grep`, you can also use `grep -e --b test` for matching `--b` in file `test`

Comment: Yes, `grep` sees the 3-character string "--b" in its `argv[1]`.  It doesn't, and can't, know that the argument was quoted or escaped on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Most of gnu utilities ignore `--options` after `--`, so you may want to do a `grep -- --b test` instead. And since you tag your question `linux`, chances are you have gnu grep.